# Drupal forum posts with images dilema

Tags: 6, nodes

I want to use Drupal to make a forum where users can post either as text or upload images. This can be achieved with the [Comment Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_upload) module.

However if you attach an image and try to post without any text, you get an error message saying *'Comment field is required.'*.

Are there any solutions to this? Is it possible to remove the validation causing this issue?

Comment: in Drupal 6, you will need to write a custom module that implements hook_form_alter() and changes the validation criteria for the Comment add/edit form. In Drupal 7, you can simply add/remove fields from comments the way you do on node types with CCK in Drupal 6. If moving to Drupal 7 is an option, I would strongly suggest doing so. If it is not, I will try to come up with a more detailed Drupal 6 solution for you.

Comment: Ill switch to 7, about time I had a look at it really. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like ['Comment Field is required' when clicking the Attach](https://www.drupal.org/node/373146) is similar (identical?) to the issue you encountered.

That issue has status *Closed (fixed)*, and also contains a [patch for it](https://www.drupal.org/node/373146#comment-1484928).